# Np random sampling in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pd data tables. I want to create a new column in df2 by assign random Rate using Weight from df1.

```
 df1 
      Income_Group      Rate     Weight
  0        1             3.5      0.5
  1        1             2.5      0.25 
  2        1             3.75     0.15
  3        1             5.0      0.15
  4        2             4.5      0.35
  5        2             2.5      0.25 
  6        2             4.75     0.20
  7        2             5.0      0.20
 ....
  30       8             2.25     0.75
  31       8             4.15     0.05
  32       8             6.35     0.20


 df2
        ID    Income_Group    State    Rate
   0    12     1              9        3.5
   1    13     2              6        4.5
   2    15     8              1        6.35
   3    8      1              5        2.5
   4    9      8              4        6.35
   5    17     2              3        4.75 
......   
  100   50     1              4        3.75
```

I tried the following code:

```
  df2['Rate']=df1.groupby('Income_Group').apply(lambda gp.np.random.choice(a=gp.Rate, p=gp.Weight,      
              replace=True))
```

Of course, the code didn't work. Can someone help me on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please try and phrase this more clearly? I am not too sure of what are you expecting as a result.

Comment: `groupby` returns an iterator.  The items in the iterator are a tuple of the value(s) for the current group and a DataFrame with rows for the current group.  So the `apply` won't work how you have it.  You need a for loop like `for income, gp in df1.groupby('Income_Group'):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is pretty small, so we can do:

```
rate_dict = df1.groupby('Income_Group')[['Rate', 'Weight']].agg(list)

df2['Rate'] = df2.Income_Group.apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(rate_dict.loc[x, 'Rate'], 
                                                  p=rate_dict.loc[x, 'Weight'])                      
                      )
```

Or you can do `groupby` on `df2` as well:

```
(df2.groupby('Income_Group')
    .Income_Group
    .transform(lambda x: np.random.choice(rate_dict.loc[x.iloc[0], 'Rate'], 
                                          size=len(x),
                                          p=rate_dict.loc[x.iloc[0], 'Weight']))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3.5,.5], [1,2.5,.25], [1,3.75,.15]],
                   columns=['Income_Group', 'Rate', 'Weight'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
weights = np.random.rand(df1.shape[0])
df2['Rate'] = df1.Rate.values * weights
```